# Error when push to heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to push my rails application to heroku and I am getting the following error

Giving the below command to push the application to heroku

git push heroku

```
BASE_URL
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   rake aborted!
   ExecJS::ProgramError: Unexpected token name «success», expected punc «,» (line: 28382, col: 5, pos: 808689)
   Error
   at new JS_Parse_Error (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:10736)
   at js_error (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:10955)
   at croak (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:18665)
   at token_error (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:18802)
   at expect_token (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:19025)
   at expect (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:19163)
   at /tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:27411
   at /tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:19536
   at expr_atom (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:26586)
   at maybe_unary (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:29260)
   at expr_ops (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:30018)
   at maybe_conditional (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:30110)
   at maybe_assign (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:30553)
   at expression (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:30866)
   at expr_list (/tmp/execjs20150113-795-19086mxjs:2316:27140)
   (in /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)/tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:64:in `extract_result'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/execjs-2.2.1/lib/execjs/external_runtime.rb:29:in `exec'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:176:in `really_compile'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/uglifier-2.1.1/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:25:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:25:in `initialize'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
   /tmp/build_e7dfa4e24f74c0bd24ba5cd9eb5bd3a4/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/sprockets-rails-2.1.4/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define'
```

Here is my application.js file

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require turbolinks
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.ui.datepicker


$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#start_date").datepicker();
   $("#end_date").datepicker();

 });
```

Please suggest where to check for resolving the error.

Comment: Check your javascript files for `success` word. You have syntax error somewhere.

Comment: @ Marek Lipka I have checked all my javascript files but still couldnt find...

Comment: $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "/events/dateFilter", 
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");},
     data: { 'start_date' : $("input[name='event[start_date]']").datepicker(), 'end_date' : $("input[name='event[end_date]']").datepicker()}
     success: function(data) { <%= render "events/dateFilter" %>}
    });

Comment: initially i had the above code in my application.js but now there is no such code in any of my javascript files...can it be related to this...any suggestions to resolve this error...

Comment: Did you do git-commit after you removed this code?

Comment: oops thanks a lot...I forgot to commit...